# How to store values ​in 2-D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class CMatrix
{
private:
    string name;
    float** matrix;
    int nRow;
    int nCol;
    int nElement;  //총 element 수

public:
    CMatrix() {
        this->name = "Anonymous";
        this->nRow = 4;
        this->nCol = 4;
        matrix = new float* [nRow];
        for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++)
            matrix[i] = new float[nCol];

        for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
    CMatrix(string _name, int _nRow, int _nCol) {
        this->nRow = _nRow;
        this->nCol = _nCol;
        this->name = _name;
        matrix = new float* [nRow];
        for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++)
            matrix[nRow] = new float[nCol];
    }

    CMatrix(CMatrix& n1);
    ~CMatrix() {};

    void setElement() {
        cout << "<Enter the elements of A>" << endl << ">>";
        for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++)
                cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    void printMatrixinfo() {
        cout << this->name << '(' << this->nRow << ", " << this->nCol << ", " << nRow * nCol << ") " <<             
    endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
            cout << "[ ";
            for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++)
                cout << matrix[nRow][nCol] << " ";
            cout << "] ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    string getName() {
        return this->name;
    }
};

void getData(string& _name, int& _nRow, int& _nCol) {
    cout << "<Enter the name , # of rows, # of cols" << endl << ">>";
    cin >> _name >> _nRow >> _nCol;
}

int main() {
    string name;
    int nRow, nCol;
    getData(name, nRow, nCol);
    CMatrix x1(name, nRow, nCol);
    x1.setElement();
    x1.printMatrixinfo();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

First, we saved values ​​in `name`, `nRow`, `nCol` through `getData` function. Then we called `CMatrix x1 (name, nRow, nCol)` to initialize the `name`, `nRow`, `nCol` of `x1`. Then, I try to put an element through the `x1.setElement()` function, but I keep getting an error. I'd appreciate it if you let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: You say you "keep getting an error"... ***What*** "error"? Is it a build error? A run-time error or crash? Unexpected output? If it's a build error then copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete error output into the question, adding comments on the lines where you get the errors. If it's a crash then catch it in a debugger and locate where in your code it happens. Mark out that line with a comment, and add the values of all involved variables. Also for run-time problems, include the exact input you give the program, and possibly the actual and expected output.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: By the way, you include `<vector>` but don't use `std::vector`? Why not? Unless this is an assignment or exercise for doing explicit memory handling yourself, you really should be using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The reason for using arrays is that the problem condition is so. In the part of setElement () function, there is an error that the exception was not handled. Can you know the problem in code? Thanks for the reply –

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information. Plus the input you give the program when running. And *please* read the links I posted earlier.

Comment: I also suggest you do some [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Find a rubber-duck (or suitable substitute, like a room-mate) and read out the code aloud to it. Doing this can help you see things in a different light. As a hint, I suggest you start with the `CMatrix(string _name, int _nRow, int _nCol)` constructor...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well I couldn't spot the problem until I got your hint.

Comment: It's a simple problem that you will discover if you look at the code you have actually written instead of just seeing the code you think you have written.

Comment: @john It is subtle, I didn't see it in my first couple of read-troughs either. :)

Comment: Thank you for the details, so I'll ask you questions carefully. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be helpful if you also add the output of the error. Other than that, I can't see a reason why you would use raw pointers, or not use `std::vector<>` or just simply use [multi-dimensional arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm). Also, you have a memory leak, make sure to delete all the `new` initialized value of the matrix in the class destructor.

Edit: I saw your edit to the question and the comment. The edit to the code still have one error, but it is not in the `setElement()` but in `void printMatrixinfo()`, specifically the line:

`cout << matrix[nRow][nCol] << " ";`

nRow and nCol is out of bounds. from the structure of your code, I guess you want to use `cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";` here instead.

and again, if this was an problem condition to use raw pointers, *dont forget to delete the matrix at destructor* (your `~CMatrix()` should not be empty!)

Comment: The reason for using arrays is that the problem condition is so.
In the part of setElement () function, there is an error that the exception was not handled. Can you know the problem in code? Thanks for the reply

Comment: If you don't have the reputation to post comments, then please be patient. Posting what is really a comment as an answer will only get it down-voted, making you loose reputation.

Comment: I'll be careful. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Actually, tried to run the updated code of @bongbong. found the error so I updated my answer. Also, bongbong make sure you are as detailed as possible on your question and you might get a quicker answer! Good luck with the coding. And yes you are right Some programmer dude, should've been patient. I updated my answer to at least point out the part of the code that needs fixing. If that's not good enough, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. From now on, I will ask you the right questions. Thanks again !